# return statement in forEach won't stop execution javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const checkAttendanceStudent = (attendance, std_id) => {
    //check if the teacher make attendance meanwhile for this current session
    let checkNow = attendance.find((element) => {
      if (checkDateAttendance(element.date)) {
        //check if the student exsit and checked first tiem in this current session
        let checkInside = element.infoDto.find((studentAT) => {
          if (parseInt(studentAT.id) === parseInt(std_id)) {
            return true;
          }
        });
        return checkInside;
      }
    });
    return checkNow === undefined ? false : true;
  };
```

How to resolve foreach problem when  iuse return to stopped it?
--- i use filter in this way, it is correct?

Comment: where is `forEach`?

Comment: It does, for the callback function. It will not terminate the loop.

Comment: Returning `true` in `find`'s callback should stop the loop indeed

Comment: Yeh, more than likely, your data simply never matches the conditions to make it true.

Comment: Please provide example input for this function that don't work

Comment: what is the purpose of `checkAttendanceStudent` what result do you want to return and where?

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and return a boolean value to stop the iteration.

The selection depends on the logical need.

Below your code with `some` instead of `find`.

```
const checkAttendanceStudent = (attendance, std_id) => 
    attendance.some(({ date, infoDto }) => 
        checkDateAttendance(date) &&
        infoDto.some(({ id }) => +id === +std_id)
    );
```

BTW, the wording of `checkAttendanceStudent` is misleading. Better is to use a wording which refects the result of the function, like `has...`or `is...` for a boolean value.

Comment: That is the answer to the **return statement in forEach won't stop execution javascript**, but that's not really what OP is asking as he/she is using `find`, not `forEach`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, no, op is searching for a boolean value. `find` returns an item, but it isn't used here, execpt of it's existence.

Answer (score -2):

Substitute forEach with while loop and boolean variabile for exit. It's the right way for handle this situation. Don't use return. I know "return" it was created and I do not resist its use, however it must be used where it is really needed. So change your piece of code with this logic

```js
while( condition && isTimeToExit == true){
.....
//Where u see what u want set isTimeToExit to true
}
```

Filter is good, but if you need to stop probably you can see other loops. Because you have reached your goal and you want to quit use standard while loop.

Comment: `for` loop would be a much better choice as a substitute of `forEach`

Comment: This is a not very optimal solution and will likely lock your code when `isTimeToExit` is accidentally never set. To break out of (nested) loops, use the `break` keyword.

Comment: @nbokmans Exit at the end of the list because the AND will no longer be true :). At anyway the use of break is legit and it work. 
The condition must also prevent out-of-bounds